# How can I ad a div spanning the width of my container using cycle in django?

Tags: django

I've kind of figured out "cycle" in Django, but not quite. The result I want is after the fourth post, directly under them I want to insert a div that spans the width of the container. So it would be four divs of equal length and the fifth div would be under those divs and would be as wide as all of them combined. heres the code I've tried that I thought would work

```
 <div class="row">
    {% for q in object_list %}

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          {% if q.image %}
            <img src='{{ q.image.url }}' class="img-responsive" />
          {% endif %}
          <div class="caption">
            <h3><a href="{{ q.get_absolute_url }}" >{{q.title}}</a><small> {{ q.timestamp|timesince }}</small></h3>
            <p>{{ q.content | truncatechars:30 }}</p>
            <p><a href="{{ q.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">view</a>
                <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' q.id %}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">delete</a>

                <a href="{% url 'posts:update' q.id %}"  class="btn btn-default" role="button">edit</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


        {% cycle "" "" "" "</div><div class='row'>" "<div class='col-sm-12' style='height: 40%; background-color: #5b80b2'></div>"%}

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I thought if I inserted the the last div after "row" and mad it 'col-sm-12' it would work how I wanted but thats not the case. any help is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. instead of

```
{% cycle "" "" "" "</div><div class='row'>" "<div class='col-sm-12' style='height: 40%; background-color: #5b80b2'></div>"%}
```

which has the div outside of the row, you do this

```
{% cycle "" "" "" "<div class='col-sm-12' style='height: 40%; background-color: #5b80b2'></div>" "</div><div class='row'>"%}
```

and put the div inside the row. Thanks to all who would have tried to help me. And I hope this helps someone using Django trying to understand "cycle".